# How can I replicate a bucket to multiple regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a bucket on one region and would like to replicate it to multiple regions. I was able to get it replicated to one more region but I don't have any options to add more replication rules and I also tried chaining the bucket I replicated into by having it in turn replicate to another bucket but that doesn't seem to be happening.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved it.

We had the same issue after the outage and want to replicate to multiple regions.

S3 (event trigger on Put) --> Lambda --> Kinesis (Stream) --> Lambda (Replicator)

when you copy the object from one region to another, check if it exists with md5 checksum.

We just add new objects, did not worry much about deletion.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the information. So basically you are saying there is no way to do this through the regular replication tools? I'm kind of new to AWS so I guess now I need to learn what Lambda is.

Comment: By replicating to 2  regions you already have 6 copies of your data. Industry standard says, you do not need more, even though it is doable by external ways.

Comment: I'm more interested on redundancy in case a data center goes down. This is for some static resources that need to always be up.

Comment: If 6 copies I meant is, 6 data centers,  SIngle AWS region comprised of multiple data centers, you have 3 copies in each region in different data centers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is an easier way - S3 supports it out of the box:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/

From the S3 console, go to the Cross-Region Replication page. It will prompt you to enable versioning if you have not already done so.

Then just choose the relevant options to enable replicating a subset or all your data, as well as where to replicate it to. You will have to create a role with enough permissions to read the source bucket and write to the target bucket.

Thus you do not need to mess with Kinesis/Lambdas.